# Is there any alternate to XUL's menulist in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do I need to make it myself?

I want: hovering like a context menu. When mouse over tree view open. If there is no space tree view appears to the left.
I want to display the menus on the sidebar.
The menus like XUL .

Example XUL:

```
<menulist>
  <menupopup>
    <menuitem label="Mozilla" value="http://mozilla.org"/>
    <menuitem label="Slashdot" value="http://slashdot.org"/>
    <menuitem label="Sourceforge" value="http://sf.net"/>
    <menuitem label="Freshmeat" value="http://freshmeat.net"/>
  </menupopup>
</menulist>
```

[image: Screenshot of what I want]

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus ?

Comment: This is not specifically a WebExtensions vs legacy extensions issue. It's HTML vs XUL. You are going to need to be *very specific* as to the functionality you are looking for, probably with screenshots/screen-casts. But, basically, yes, you will need to implement whatever it is you want yourself in HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: You're going to need a more complex `<menulist>` example, as what you have in the question is equivalent to a simple [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Comment: Also, from your description of what you are wanting, it's XUL's [`<menu>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/menu), [`<menupopup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/menupopup), etc. which you are probably interested in, not [`<menulist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/menulist).

Comment: Please [edit] your question. It's unclear because the example you have provided does not exhibit the behavior you've requested be duplicated.

Comment: I want to display the same behavior as the context menu on the sidebar.

Comment: You want your menu to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeZPd.png ? Can you edit your question to add an image description for that? For one thing, you need to use HTML and CSS, and we think you're trying to use XUL. Maybe you can find what you want at http://navnav.co/.

Comment: Also, on Stack Overflow, you should show us what you've tried, and ask for help in making it work. It sounds like you're asking someone to design your menu for you, and I'm not sure that's what you want.